# Storm release download site no longer accessible?

Tags: apache-storm

I downloaded storm package from https://github.com/apache/storm/releases, but seems that's just source code:

```
root@ bin]# ./storm
******************************************
The storm client can only be run from within a release. You appear to be trying to run the client from a checkout of Storm's source code.

You can download a Storm release at http://storm-project.net/downloads.html
******************************************
```

But http://storm-project.net/downloads.html just returns 404 to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to download the latest version is the following:

https://storm.apache.org/downloads.html

Just pick the zip of whatever version you are looking for.